# Text is being squished in from the right and I don't know why :(

Tags: html, css, indentation

My text is indented and I’m not sure why. I’ve gone through my code and I don’t see any margins or paddings that might be influencing it to do this.

Website: http://www.cubistphotographics.com.au/weddings.html (please use Firefox; the page is currently not compatable with Chrome).

[What the website looks like in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCGEi.png)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  color: white
}

.inner-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 8vw;
  width: 100%;
}

.abt-txt-wedding {
  font-family: lato-semibold;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 5vw;
}

.icon-pos-wedding {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vw;
  left: vw;
  color: black;
  font-family: lato-black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <img src="gallery/23.jpg" style="width:100%;">

  <div class="inner-container">

    <img src="gallery/head.jpg" style="width:100%;">

    <div class="icon-pos-wedding">

      <div class="abt-txt-wedding">

        <h1>Weddings</h1>

        <p>
          Peter believes that couples should be treated as individuals with their wedding photographs reflecting their individual qualities. He understands the importance of capturing emotions and feelings that people experience on their wedding day and wants a
          stress free and enjoyable experience for all involved. He was a firm believer in the yes vote and is looking forward to the opportunity to photograph many LGBT weddings. Peter's style is a unique blend of contemporary imagery combined with natural,
          candid glimpses.
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `width:100%;` to your `.abt-txt-wedding` class

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting everthing and the .inner-container has padding on it. Then there was a typo in the .icon-pos - missing the number of the vw.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  color: white
}

.inner-container {
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; padding: 8vw;width: 100%;
  }


.abt-txt-wedding{
    font-family: lato-semibold;
    font-size: 1.3vw;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
     position: absolute;
     margin: 0;
     left: 5vw;
    width:100%
     

  }

  .icon-pos-wedding {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10vw;
      left: 0;
      color: black;
      font-family: lato-black;
      width: 100%
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="gallery/23.jpg" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <img src="gallery/head.jpg" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="icon-pos-wedding">
      <div class="abt-txt-wedding" >
        <h1>Weddings</h1>
          <p>Peter believes that couples should be treated as individuals with their wedding photographs reflecting their individual qualities. He understands the importance of capturing emotions and feelings that people experience on their wedding day and wants a stress free and enjoyable experience for all involved. He was a firm believer in the yes vote and is looking forward to the opportunity to photograph many LGBT weddings. Peter's style is a unique blend of contemporary imagery combined with natural, candid glimpses.</p>
     </div>
    </div >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but my issue is that my text is getting squished in from the right for some reason so that the paragraph is only 3 words long. I don't know why its being padded in.

Comment: @strugglingStudent - check the answer now - by adding a width:100% to the nested elements - it displays across the page. Is that what tyou are after? also - you don't really need to use position absolute at all - just deal with the layout with padding of hte parent elements.